# Adjusting horizontal spacings around product signs, in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vector, horizontal, tensor

This issue may be inexistent to the eyes of most people, but it currently scroches my aesthetical eyes!

I would like to adjust the spacings around the usual product signs (**scalar product**, **vectorial and tensorial products**, ...), to get a more balanced output when vectors and tensors have indices or exponents.  Here's a MWE code to show the issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\newcommand*{\bvec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ssp}{\mskip1mu} % mu = "math unit". Simple space \, = 3mu.
\newcommand*{\psp}{\mskip2mu} % 2mu ; approx 1.2pt.

\begin{document}

Default spacing around product signs:
    \begin{gather}
        \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \cdot \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \times \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \wedge \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \otimes \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}. \\[1ex]
        \bvec{a} \cdot \bvec{b} \ne \bvec{a} \times \bvec{b} \ne \bvec{a} \wedge \bvec{b} \ne \bvec{a} \otimes \bvec{b}.
    \end{gather}
More space on right of the product signs:
    \begin{gather}
        \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \cdot \ssp \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \times \ssp \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \wedge \ssp \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \otimes \ssp \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}.
    \end{gather}
    Less space on left of product sides:
    \begin{gather}
        \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \!\psp \cdot \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \!\psp \times \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \!\psp \wedge \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}
        \ne \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_i} \!\psp \otimes \tensor{\bvec{e}}{_j}.
    \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Preview (the spacing issue is subtle, maybe not visible on a first look):

[image]

In the default case (first two equation lines), the spacings around the product sign aren't well balanced because of the index (see equation (1)).  There seems to be more space on the left side than on the right side.  The spacing feels perfect when the vectors don't have any index (line (2)).  Currently, I could add a small space by hand on the right, like on line (3).  But the result isn't very appealing.

I could also reduce a bit the space on the left side, like on line (4).  The result is almost right to my eyes.  But I wonder if there's a better way of doing this, maybe without doing it by hand in each case.  I also had to hack the product by eye, using an arbitrary small space (one third of a regular `\,` space)

So how could we adjust the spacing/kerning around the product signs to get well balanced math expressions in all cases (with and without any lower or upper indices)?

**Important:**  Take note that I don't want to create new macros to redefine all of the products as two entry functions: I don't want products as "machines with slots".  I may have to redefine the products without adding entries to them, though, but I would prefer the simplest thing possible.

---

**EDIT:** Maybe the best way is to redefine the product commands (`\times`, `\cdot`, `\otimes`, `\wedge`, `\odot`) to add an optional spacing argument, but I need your suggestions to implement the idea.  So let the new `\times` command stays the same as the old `\times` when no argument is added to it, and `\times[?]` (or `\times{?}` ??) be the command with a **negative space added to the left side**.  How to do that in a proper way?

I would like to replace the default `\times` to something like `\!\ssp \times`, or maybe `\!\psp \times`, from a new `\times` with an optional argument (one third or two third of negative space).

Comment: Changing `\medmuskip` will adjust spacing around the operators, but will do so symmetrically.  I had posted such an answer, but deleted it after it seemed you wanted a nonuniform (more on left than right) increase.

Comment: What you are asking is essentially “optically balanced space” around binary operators, which is very subjective by nature. For example, should the space after `e_i` be slightly smaller than the space after `e_k` or `e_l` so they “look” the same, because of the absence of ascender subscript in the former case and the presence of ascending letter in the latter? This is a problem of design decision: For a system of rigorous mathematics typesetting, do you really want “optical” alignment/balance, or “mathematical” alignment/balance?

Comment: @RuixiZhang, I don't know the difference.  I want "optical balance" of some sort, so the products feel well balanced when the first vector has an index (may be greek, or latin).  I may do it by hand, like what I did, but I'm looking for some natural way of doing it, instead of a kind of cheap "hack".

Comment: Like I said, “looking and feeling balanced” is very subjective. When I commented about “mathematical balance”, I meant TeX had typeset your formula as `e_i <space for binary symbol> <product symbol> <space for binary symbol> e_j`, where the two spaces are “mathematically equal”. To my eyes, the product symbol “looks” already balanced, for vectors with or without indices.

Comment: If subscripts really bother you, you can try another global solution: `\setlength{\scriptspace}{0pt}`, or even `\setlength{\scriptspace}{-0.5pt}`.

Comment: You can do it with Lua by checking whether the atom (or submlist) before the binary operator has a sub (or sup) field.